# Error while installing packages in R

Tags: r

i am trying to install a packages in R, via R Studio, and I have the following error:

```
installing the source package ‘bizdays’

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  153k  100  153k    0     0  82372      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 82393
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R: line 261: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R: No such file or directory
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R: line 261: exec: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/exec/R: cannot execute: No such file or directory
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘bizdays’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/z9/vfdjnsxx5zv15kdvfdy65trh0000gn/T/RtmpvkSXSt/downloaded_packages’
```

I am using Mac OS. Does anyone know how to go around or fix this one please?

Comment: If you have `devtools` installed try: `devtools::install_github('R-bizdays', username='wilsonfreitas')`

Comment: Ok, thank you @patl.

Comment: Could you install it?